# Java: Updating UI while waiting for another thread to finish

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread

I have some Java Swing login panel. When user click "login" button, extensive DB communication takes place. I got an idea to put that db communication into another thread (that db communication is used for filling some hash maps and singletons). After putting that communication into separate thread, db heavy lifting takes place while user is typing it's uname and password. When user clicks "login" button, than code will wait for "heavy lifting" thread to join, and then proceed.

The problem is that while my code is waiting for db thread to join, it seems that no UI updates can be done. I don't think i can use SwingWorker for db communication because user can click "login" button any time, even before SW would finish and i don't have a way to join SwingWorker (db communication has to take place BEFORE actual login).

Is there a way to enable Swing ui updates while waiting for another thread to join? Am i missing something?

Comment: 1. Do you mean you want to update the UI after entering credentials and clicking login?  Like updating a progress bar or something?  Or do you just want the user to be able enter credentials and click login, then do nothing until the DB task is completed?

Comment: 2. What java concurrency mechanism are you currently using?  (plain Threads, ThreadPools, Executors, ...) ?

Comment: I'm using plain Threads. @herman: i want to start loading "pre login" data and then check uname and pass, but if user quickly enters credentials and clicks login, i want to finish preload and then continue checking uname and pass

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put two flags and at the end of both operations (DB-communication and user click), call the same method and verify there the state of the two flags. Possibly show a progress bar in a modal dialog if you want to block user input:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestThreadJoin {

    private boolean dbWorkDone = false;
    private boolean credentialsProvided = false;
    private JTextField loginTF;
    private JTextField passwordTF;

    protected void initUI() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestThreadJoin.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JLabel login = new JLabel("Login: ");
        JLabel password = new JLabel("Password: ");
        loginTF = new JTextField(20);
        passwordTF = new JPasswordField(20);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        panel.add(login, gbc);
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        panel.add(loginTF, gbc);
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        panel.add(password, gbc);
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        panel.add(passwordTF, gbc);
        JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
        loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                credentialsProvided = true;
                proceed();
            }
        });
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.add(loginButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                super.done();
                dbWorkDone = true;
                proceed();
            }
        };
        worker.execute();
    }

    protected void proceed() {
        if (credentialsProvided && dbWorkDone) {
            System.err.println("Continuing ");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
            UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestThreadJoin().initUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll accept this solution. It's complete, and looks like it would work for me. Even if not, some of it's derivates will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done using SwingWorker.
Add this ActionListener to your JButton. Also provide JLabel field for 'label' & JProgressBar field for 'progressbar'.

```
java.awt.event.ActionListener al = new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        SwingWorker swingWorker = new SwingWorker() {

            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {

                // SIMULATE DB WORK
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        this.wait(300);
                    }
                    publish(10 * i);
                }
                publish(100);

                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                label.setText("Work complete");
                button.setEnable(true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void process(List chunks) {
                for (Object object : chunks) {
                    Integer progress = (Integer) object;
                    progressBar.setValue(progress);
                }
            }

        };

        button.setEnable(false);
        swingWorker.execute();
    }
}
```

Since DB work may not be quantifiable (measurable), do the following changes:

- insert 'progressbar.setIndeterminate(true)' above the 'swingWorker.execute()' line,
- insert 'progressbar.setIndeterminate(false)' above 'label.setText()' line,
- remove 'publish(int)' calls.

Comment: The problem is that another half of login process is done in another class. From swing worker i can't really know if user have already clicked login button or not, and from that other class i can't really tell if swing worker has done it's work (stage 1 login) or say "stop stage 2 login until swing worker is done"...

Comment: If you attach the ActionListener to the Login button, you would know the moment the button is pressed and then executing the swingWorker. Inside the swingWorker.doInBackground(), perform your login call, e.g. Controller.login(name, pwd). Read up on "MVC pattern" to know more.

Answer (score 2):

I really think you should give the SwingWorker a try, by doing something like:

- when the user clicks login, start the swing worker (new Swingworker<...,...>().execute();)
- in the **doInBackground()**, call **pusblih()** first to call **process()** to disable the button
- then wait for the background thread in **doInBackground()**
- in the **done()** update the UI

this way you will not freeze the EDT...

Another option would be to run you own "mini-swingworker":

```
loginButton.setEnabled(false);  // assuming this runs in the EDT
new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    myOtherBgThread.join();  // here we wait for the BG thread
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      // go back into the EDT
      // update the UI here...
    }
  }
}.start();
```

hope it helps, regards

Comment: The problem is that another half of login process is done in another class. From swing worker i can't really know if user have already clicked login button or not (or pressed "Enter" in password filed!), and from that other class i can't really tell if swing worker has done it's work (stage 1 login) or say "stop stage 2 login until swing worker is done"...

Answer (score 1):

1. One of the simplest solutions would be to disable Login button before the initial DB communication finishes. But that would require some additional progress bar or message that the initialization takes place not to confuse the users. In this case you could use `SwingWorker` which enables the Login button upon finish.
2. Another solution is that the when the user presses the Login button, the handling should be again delegated to (another) background thread which waits for the initial DB communication thread to join. This way EDT (and GUI) will not be blocked. Actually connecting to DB is also a lengthy operation so it should be done in a background thread anyway, even  when disabling the Login button as described in 1.
3. Yet another solution is to create a thread pool of fixed size 1 (eg. `java.util.concurrent.Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`) and pass all background tasks there. With single thread executor tasks will be performed in sequential order. The first task would be the initial DB communication, another one the login task.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ExecutorService.  Call `executorService.submit(runnable)` where 'runnable' performs the DB work.  The `submit` method will return a `Future`.  Then after login you can call `future.get()` which will wait for completion (or return immediately if the runnable had already completed).

Comment: I have used ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor, submitted that db thread, but again - calling "Future.get" blocks UI until Executor is done...

Comment: at the time you call that, the login button has been clicked already, so why do you need to be able to update the UI while waiting?  can't you update the UI first, then call get()?

Comment: Well in case of autologin stage 2 follows stage 1 immediately. In case of manual login stage 1 is done while user is typing, stage 2 starts after click on "login" button and that might be after or before stage 1 (db thread) has finished. Stage 2 is SHARED - both manual and auto login use the same method. In case of autologin different UI has to be shown and stage 1 and stage 2 are called right away. Because of "stage1.join" it can be done, but then because of "join", loding UI is flashed AFTER everything is done.

Comment: @guest86 Calling `get()` on the EDT is a bad idea. It will freeze the UI. None of join(), wait(), sleep(), etc... will solve this situation.